# Print function not printing results

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for a simple game. Starting with a base but I am facing very annoying error (rather a glitch).

```
import random
winning_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
allowed_numbers_single_digit = random.randint(1, 10)
allowed_numbers_single_digit2 = random.randint(1, 10)
allowed_numbers_single_digit3 = random.randint(1, 10)
allowed_numbers_single_digit4 = random.randint(1, 10)
middle_column_numbers = (10, 15, 20, 25)
right_column_numbers = (50, 75, 100)

double_digit_allowed = random.choice(middle_column_numbers) 
double_high_digits = random.choice(right_column_numbers)

print(f"""Number that we are looking for is {winning_number}. 
You may use {allowed_numbers_single_digit, allowed_numbers_single_digit2, allowed_numbers_single_digit3, 
             allowed_numbers_single_digit4, double_digit_allowed, double_high_digits}
 """)
x = input()
print(x)

if winning_number != x:
    print('Sorry, no points for you')
else:
    print('You got 10 points!')
```

Glitch that I am talking about: when user inputs numbers to string 'x', next line writes pretty much the same. Eg: if user entered 6+5, print would print out 6+5 rather than 11.
Any tips?

Comment: Of course `print(x)` will print the same as you input, since nothing happens in between . Please state your expectations as well.

Answer (score 3):

When the user inputs `x` you get a string, and it is not evaluated. If you want to evaluate the expression they wrote, you can do

```
x = eval(input())
```

In this case `x` will be an integer.

If you just want to parse an inputted string into an integer, (will not support + or - or whatever), you can do

```
x = int(input())
```

#### Edit:

`eval` is potentially dangerous and can actually let the user cheat in this case. If the user types `winning_number`, the winning number will be selected.

Instead you can use `literal_eval` to avoid this.

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

This restricts the user from using variables defined in the rest of the program, and from running any code.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mime obligatory [Why eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: If you want to limit `eval`, you can instead `import ast`, and then use `ast.literal_eval`. This will prevent the user from doing anything dangerous.

Comment: @blackbrandt I don't think he will try to kill his own computer but it is good to know :D

Comment: It's best to avoid `eval` as it could be used by malicious attackers to hack your computer / purge all your files / do all sorts of evil things.

Comment: @blackbrandt Thanks for this - read it and did not know about this. However, this is just my simple tackles to create simple word and number games as I am still learning, and this small application will never be released to public. Still thank you very much for this my friend!

Comment: @Mime I totally understand that on this application. However, as it sounds like you are a beginner, it is always better to understand good habits from the beginning rather than have to break said habits months or years down the line.

Comment: @Mime I thought `eval` shouldn't be a problem as well, but even with simple stuff it's better to write it as if this code does get out to the public. Later on you might come up to a similar problem but you only learned to do it in an unsafe way and have to learn the safe way anyway.